# how to detect the change of the value of a given cell by a function

Tags: vba

I like that you gave me a solution for the following problems:
I have financial data that change randomly in a cell, saying A1, provided by a software of finance, I want to record these data one after one in a column, I already wrote this small code but it does not detect the change in the value of A1 because cell A1 contains a function given by the software

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A1"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Call test
End If
End Sub

Sub test()
Static n As Integer
n = Cells(1, 3).Value ' used for the faste verification of empty cells 
    While Not IsEmpty(Cells(n, 1))
        n = n + 1
    Wend
    Cells(n, 1).Value = Cells(1, 1).Value
    Cells(1, 3).Value = n
End Sub
```

Comment: You are correct, `Worksheet_Change` does not fire when a cell function recalculates. If you know what cells that function in `A1` depends on, then track changes in those cells instead. Otherwise handle the `Worksheet_Calculate` event.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to create a function that takes the cells you would like to track as an argument. That way, changes to the cell values (arguments) would generate a call to the tracking function.

Something like this will track how many times the function is called:

```
Dim i As Integer
Function tracker(c As Variant) As Integer
    i = i + 1
    tracker = i
End Function
```